# When entering text in a field, the associated label disappears: How to find guilty JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Generally speaking, I'm a decent programmer, (C++, Java, Ruby, Python) but I at the *very* starting point of learning Javascript.  I'm debugging inherited code (so I'm unfamiliar with it) and the current problem is that whenever I click a text field, the associated label goes away.

How can I tell what JS is causing this?

(My browser of choice is Chrome.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Install the Firebug extension for Firefox. In the HTML tab there's a button "break on mutate" which will act as a breakpoint that triggers as soon as the DOM is modified. This should help you finding out what script is causing your issue.

Comment: That's cool.  Do you know if there is a similar solution for Chrome?

Comment: I found something for Chrome... but I don't know how to use it.  If you go to Inspect Element, then under the scripts tab at the right there under Event Listener Breakpoints there is a DOM mutation check box.  I think this is at least enough for a good ol' fashion Google search.